# Accessibility issue with a <main> tag in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, modal-dialog, accessibility

I currently receive this error by axe:

```
Document does not have one main landmark.
```

I then put the main landmark where it is needed and then axe says:

```
Document has more than one main landmark.
```

This is the structure:

```
<main>
   <p> some text </>
</main>
<form>
   <PopupModalFromBootstrap isVisible={isVisible} />
</form>
```

The problem with the main tag occurs only when the modal is visible.
When the modal is not visible I do not get this error.

I tried to put the  tag in literally every place possible in the code and whenever the modal is visible I keep getting one of both error messages. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: what is the outputted HTML it is difficult to help without seeing that I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, so apologies if I'm leading you astray, but according to [Dequeue University's article here](https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/4.1/landmark-one-main?application=axeAPI), to assist screen readers in processing a page, the basic structure should be as follows.

```
<header role="banner">
   <p>Put company logo, etc. here.</p>
</header>
<nav role="navigation">
   <ul>
      <li>Put navigation here</li>
   </ul>
</nav>
<main role="main">
   <p>Put main content here.</p>
</main>
<footer role="contentinfo">
   <p>Put copyright, etc. here.</p>
</footer>
```

So, the markup you included above should look more like this.

```
<main role="main">
   <p> some text </>
   <form>
      <PopupModalFromBootstrap isVisible={isVisible} />
   </form>
</main>
```

It does seem pretty redundant putting `role="main"` on a `<main>` tag, and in that article it does state that it's just a [belt and braces](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/belt-and-braces.html) approach for now, and that it won't be necessary in future accessibility guidelines.